# Usage for xsl param in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, vxml

I defined a param array `$gen` as:

```
<xsl:variable name="inline-array">
    <item>western</item>
    <item>Romance</item>
    <item>Adventure</item>
    <item>Drama</item>
    <item>Comedy</item>
    <item>Horror</item>
    <item>Action</item>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:param name="gen" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='inline-array']/*"/>
```

I want to transfer a XML to VXML by XSLT.
Param `$gen` and `$gen2` failed to select the value when I used it in Xpath

```
<xsl:value-of select>:
    <filled namelist="MovieSummary">
      <if cond="MovieSummary == '{$gen[1]}'">
        <prompt>
            <xsl:value-of select ="//genre[.='western']/../title"/>. <xsl:value-of select ="//genre[.='western']/../summary"/>
        </prompt>
    <xsl:for-each select="$gen[position()>1]">        
        <xsl:variable name="gen2"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
        <elseif cond="MovieSummary == '{$gen2}'"/>
        <prompt>
            <xsl:value-of select ="//genre[.='$gen2']/../title"/>. <xsl:value-of select ="//genre[.='$gen2']/../summary"/>
        </prompt>   
    </xsl:for-each>
 <else/>
 </if> 
 </filled>
```

It failed to select the value when I use `$gen2` instead of "Romance" or other string. But `cond="MovieSummary == '{$gen[1]}'"` works well.
It can only generate something like:

```
  <if cond="MovieSummary == 'western'">`enter code here`
    <prompt>Range Feud. 
    Clint Turner is arrested for the murder of his girlfriend Judy's      
    father, a rival rancher who was an enemy of his own father.
    </prompt>
    <elseif cond="MovieSummary == 'Romance'"/>
    <prompt>. </prompt>
     <else/>
  </if>
```

I've tried:

```
select ="//genre[.=$gen2]/../summary"; 
select ="//genre[.={$gen2}]/../summary"; 
select ="//genre[.='{$gen2}']/../summary"
```

All failed.

Comment: Most of the code you posted isn't visible. Format it so that it is visible. And I'm not sure if you have provided enough data to work on.

Comment: Please post a complete, reproducible example (including an input) and state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$gen[position()>1]">
```

puts you in the context of `$gen`. From this context, the expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="//genre[.='$gen2']/../title"/>
```

selects nothing, because `//` starts from the root of the current document - but `genre` is in another document altogeher.

You need to change the context back to the processed XML document in order to address the nodes within it.

*Note: in XSLT 2.0, the `key()` function can select nodes in another document directly, without changing the overall context.*

Comment: @Mayoco I cannot help you further unless you post a [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Good answer. Can you please provide an example of changing the context back to the current/processed document? I mean: a way to change the context of the currently processed node back from `document('')/...` to the current document?

Comment: @zx485 There are only two ways to change context. I will provide an example after OP provides an example of the input.

Comment: I change the instruction to**<xsl:for-each select="//movie[genre=$gen[position()>1]]">** and change the prompt context. It works! Thank you!